# Proper way to add event to control library

Tags: c#

I'm writing a Winforms Control, that wraps a JS library and extends a web browser control.

When the JS library, calls an event, I have a callback to a method in C# that parses the returned JSON etc... At the end of that method, I want to fire an event, with the data returned from JS.

I'm doing the following:

```
public event EventHandler<WebMercatorCoordinates> OnMapClick;
public void JavascriptCallbackReceiver(String message)
        {
           //I'm parsing the string here
           if (OnMapClick != null)
                this.OnMapClick(this, new WebMercatorCoordinates(lat, lng));
        }
```

I do not like that null check. I have to check for it, so as to not call a null delegate, if the user has not added his own handler to `EventHandler<WebMercatorCoordinates> OnMapClick` .

Should I, in the constructor of the class, add a handler to the event so that it is never null (the object will catch its own event)? I don't like that either (sounds way worse).

Is there some better way to design/wirte this?

Comment: Read [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229011(v=vs.100).aspx). Your way of event rising is not thread safe (accessing `OnMapClick` twice, consider to use local variable or use `?.Invoke` syntax from c# 6.0), it's better to inherit delegate parameter from `EventArgs` than to use it directly, consider to put event rising code into `protected OnEvent` method (and do not name event `OnSomething`, use e.g. `MapClicked`). Have you checked `code-review` tag tooltip btw?

Comment: Yes I have checked the tooltip :P I figured it's not appropriate for code review SE, since I know that it's not quite correct. Thank you very much for the input, I didn't know about these guidelines!

Comment: I've removed the `code-review` tag, since it's not very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the C# 6 [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) you can write:

```
OnMapClick?.Invoke(this, new WebMercatorCoordinates(lat, lng));
```